# How to create a sub-query with a combination of two tables

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need help coming up with a query that join 2 tables and comes out with a matrix like this:

table 1:

```
month
january-2022
february-2022
march-2022
```

table 2:

```
client_id
100123
100124
100125
```

table 3 outcome:

```
month           client_id
january-2022    100123
february-2022   100123
march-2022      100123
january-2022    100124
february-2022   100124
march-2022      100124
january-2022    100125
february-2022   100125
march-2022      100125
```

Any ideas on how could I do that via Redshift SQL?
Thanks in advance

edit: I've corrected the expected results, it was wrong, thanks @thorsten kettner for pointing it out.

Comment: `SELECT t1.month, t2.client_id FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2;`. Really all you want is to have both tables in your `FROM` clause with no join condition. This produces the cartesian product/cross-join you are after.

Comment: Are you sure you want three rows with 100123/january, three rows with 100124/february and three rows with 100125/march? Or do you rather want a cross join, i.e. combine every month with every client_id? The latter would be `select t1.month, t2.client_id from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2` in proper standard SQL. (We stopped using commas in the from clause some decades ago.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> select t1.month, t2.client_id from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2 in
> proper standard SQL. (We stopped using commas in the from clause some
> decades ago.) –  Thorsten Kettner  2 days ago

Thorsten Kettner solved it in the comments, thanks.